# Get text from clicked td-tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, dreamweaver

I've been stuck on this piece of code for a while now. I just want a phrase  to increase in size, after I click a td-element with the numeric font-size as text.

jQuery code:

```
$('td').click(function() {
        var string = $('this').html();
        alert(string);
        $('#tekstPreview').css("font-size", string);
        });
```

table:

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="10" id="table">


<tr>
    <td height="20" width="20">9</td>
    <td height="20" width="20">10</td>
    <td height="20" width="20">12</td>
    <td height="20" width="20">14</td>
    <td height="20" width="20">16</td>
    <td height="20" width="20">18</td>
    <td height="20" width="20">20</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The only thing the alert-statement returns me is "undefined". I doesn't work either if I use .text() or .value() (which makes sense).

Comment: `$(this).text()` or `$(this).html()`

Answer (score 3):

The `this` should not be in `quotes` , putting `this` in quotes mean you are looking for tags type `this`, You also need to define element with id `tekstPreview`. Also append "px" after the size to have the font change.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4rSLV/)**

*Change*

```
var string = $('this').html();
```

*To*

```
var string = $(this).html();
```

Your code would be

```
$('td').click(function () {
    var string = $(this).html();   
    $('#tekstPreview').css("font-size", string + "px");
});
```

Comment: Note that your demo has another important change not shown in your answer (`+ "px"`)...

Comment: what a rookie mistake, been programming for too many hours straight!

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
$('td').click(function() {
    var string = $(this).html(); //change 'this' to this
    alert(string);
    $('#tekstPreview').css("font-size", string+"px"); // add px at the end
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Change** `$(this)` **To** `$('this')`

You are trying to convert string to jQuery object not the javascript object this.

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/GrkW5/)

Answer (score 0):

Try with

`$(this).html();` or `$(this).text();`

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/x8B8c/8/)

Answer (score 0):

As much as I hate drowning in a sea of answers that work, this one is made special:

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/seRa3/)

### jQuery:

```
$('#table').on('click', 'td', function () {
    var string = $(this).text();
    $(this).css({fontSize: string+'px'});
});
```

Instead of your `#tekstPreview` I just made each number change its own size for proof-of-concept.